# How do I sort Django models by sum of calculated property?

Tags: django, database, django-orm

I have two models, Project and Session. One project has many sessions, one user has many projects:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = [models.functions.Lower("name")]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Session(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
    timezone = TimeZoneField()
    breaks = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def duration(self):
        # returns minutes in (end - start)
```

I want a way to get all projects for a given user, sorted by the sum of duration in all its sessions. As `session.duration()` is not a database field, but rather is calculated from database fields, I cannot get this information in a single database query.

My current solution is:

```
sessions = Session.objects.filter(project__user=self)
groups = [[a, sum([s.duration() for s in b])] for a, b in groupby(
 sessions, key=lambda s: s.project
)]
groups = sorted(groups, key=lambda g: g[1], reverse=True)
return [g[0] for g in groups]
```

This gets all relevant sessions in a single query, but then I group them by project and this takes too long - about a second when there are about a 100 projects. Is there a way to accomplish this that takes less time? And ideally doesn't require a database call for every project?

I am using Django 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotations and aggregation to achieve this. First, modify the Session model a bit by changing this line:

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

to this:

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='sessions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

-now every `Project` instance will have a `sessions` field, which will contain the queryset of all `Session`s related to that `Project`.

Instead of taking all user sessions like you do now, you can take all user's Projects and loop through each project's Sessions like:

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(user=self)
for p in projects:
    sessions = p.sessions.all()
```

Then you can manipulate the `sessions` queryset, annotating them with an expression field like:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, fields

duration_ = ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - F('start'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
sessions = p.sessions.annotate(d=duration_)
```

At this point each member of the `sessions` queryset will have a field named `d` holding the duration of the sorresponding `Session`.
To sum the durations, we can use the **aggregation** feature of Django querysets, like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
total = sessions.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('d'))["total_duration"]
```

What we're doing on the 2nd line is creating a single element from a queryset (*"aggregating"* it), by adding all the values in the `d` field, and assigning the result to a field called `total_duration`. The result of this expression:

```
sessions.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('d'))
```

is a `dict` with only one key (`total_duration`), from which we take the value.

Next, you can build a list of projects and durations, and sort it afterwards by duration, e.g. like this:

```
import operator
plist = []
for p in projects:
    sessions = p.sessions.annotate(d=duration_)
    total = sessions.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('d'))["total_duration"]
    # total holds the sum of this project's sessions
    plist.append({'p':p,'total':total})
plist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('total'))

projects = [item['p'] for item in plist]
```

To sum it up:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import F, Sum, ExpressionWrapper, fields

duration_ = ExpressionWrapper(F('end') - F('start'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
projects = Project.objects.filter(user=self)
plist = []

for p in projects:
    sessions = p.sessions.annotate(d=duration_)
    total = sessions.aggregate(total_duration=Sum('d'))["total_duration"]
    # total holds the sum of this project's sessions
    plist.append({'p':p,'total':total})

plist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('total'))

projects = [item['p'] for item in plist]
```

Reference: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32856190/719247), [Django Query Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/), [Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset)

Comment: Thank you for this - I'm still a little unclear though. Here `total` is the sum of every session's duration. The output I need is a list of projects sorted by total duration of that project's sessions. I feel like you've got 90% of the way there, I just can't work out how to use the duration_ field above to achieve that.

Comment: @SamIreland I've updated my answer. Now it should be complete.